# Is sharepoint online allowing us to view more thean 5,000 items on our list views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, list-view-threshold, threshold

I have a custom list which currently contain 7500 items as follow:-
[image]

and i have our list view which show all items without filtering and sorted by modified date as follow:-
[image]

now i thought that i will get threshold error on the list view, but seems it allow us to view all the data and apply field-based filtering and sorting on index columns inside classic UI and even doing filtering on non-index columns inside modern UI.. so has SharePoint recently changed/expanded the threshold list view limitation to allow viewing more than 5000 items?

**Second question**, now on the same list i wrote the following CAML query to filter based on an indexed column:-

```
query1.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name ='CustomerOrderAlert0'/><Value Type='Choice'>Yes</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>3000</RowLimit></View>";
```

now the query will work well if the results will be lower 5,000 while if the result of the filter will be more than 5,000 i will get this error inside the code:-

```
'The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.'
```

so why SharePoint allow viewing more than 5,000 items on list views while does not allow this inside CAML queries?

Answer (score 1):

The Modern experience allows more than 5000 items in a list view.

CAML is the query language of the Classic experience and cannot use the algorithms of the modern experience to return more than 5000 items.

See [this Microsoft Support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

> You can store up to 30 million items or files in a SharePoint list or
>   library. Filtered views of large lists have a similar experience to
>   other lists. However, when a list view shows more than 5000 items, you
>   may run into a list view threshold error. To update your list when you
>   do, perform one or all of the following three steps.
>
> [...]
>
> Use modern Views showing many items work best in the modern
>   experience. To avoid errors you might see in the classic experience,
>   use the modern experience.

Comment: but based on my test even using classic UI i was able to view the 7,500 items inside the list view

Comment: did you notice the language? " ... views showing many items work best in the modern experience ...." It doesn't say that it won't work at all  in the classic experience. I've worked with views showing more than 5000 items in SharePoint 2010. It may work in certain scenarios in classic. But it "works best" in modern.